# Помогите с программой на Pascal

Tags: математика, pascal

[image: Это выражению по которому написан код]

Сверху выражение по которому написан код,  (f1-f3) - числа Фибоначчи

```
var 
eps: real; 
sum: real; 
summand: real;
 fib, fibPrev, fibPrevPrev: real; 
 fragment: real; 
 number: integer; 
 begin
 write('Введите eps: ');
 readln(eps);
 summand := 36 * sqrt(2);
 sum := summand; 
 fibPrevPrev := 0;
 fibPrev := 1;
 fragment := 36;
 number := 2; 
 while summand > eps do
         begin fib := fibPrevPrev 
  + fibPrev; 
         fibPrevPrev := fibPrev; 
         fibPrev := fib;
          fragment := fragment * 6 
  / number;
           number := number + 1; 
           summand := fib * 
   fragment * sqrt(number);
            sum := sum + summand; 
            end; 
            write(sum:10:5);
             end.
```

у меня вопрос почему значение fragment = 36; и где программа вычесляет числа Фибоначчи и фактериалы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `fragment = 36` потому что степень `6` в приведенном вами ряде начинается с `2`; а 6 во второй степени = 36. А в знаменателе там `1`. Любое число делить на `1` - то же число.
2. числа фибоначи вычисляются в начале цикла вот в этих строках

```
fib := fibPrevPrev 
  + fibPrev; 
         fibPrevPrev := fibPrev; 
         fibPrev := fib;
```

3. Факториал в приведенном коде отдельно не считается. Вместо этого пересчитывается `fragment`:

```
fragment := fragment * 6 
  / number;
```

Если домножить `n`-ый числитель (`6**n / n!`), исключая число фибоначи и корень, на `6/(n+1)`, то получим `6**(n+1) / (n+1)!`.

---

Примечание: `a**b` - `a` в степени `b`.

Comment: а почему тогда корень из 2 в fragment не записан ?

Comment: @Lucifer04 потому что корень в каждом `n` высчитвается заново вот тут `summand := fib * 
   fragment * sqrt(number);`. корень от `n+1` не имеет смысла вычислять из корня из `n`

Comment: можете пожалуйста еще подробно объяснить это: fragment := fragment * 6 / number;

Comment: @Lucifer04 я уже объяснил в пнкт.3 ответа, что именно вам не понятно ?

Comment: я не понимаю как именно и ЗАЧЕМ пересчитывается fragment.

Comment: и кстати, если `fibPrevPrev := 0;` заменить на `fibPrevPrev := 1;`, то программа измениться? Просто я считаю Фибоначчи с 1 1 2, а не с 0.

Comment: `fragment` пересчитавается для того, чтобы соответствовать формуле. считать факториал числа на каждой итерации - это не рационально. лучше на каждой следующей итерации домножить факториал предыдущего числа на текущий порядковый номер, что и делается. со степень числа (в данном случае `6` - та же история). можно было бы разделить фрагмент на две переменные: одну для `6**n`, а другую для `n!`, но автор кода решил сделать это в одной переменной.

Comment: да, измениться, если поменять с 0 на 1. результаты будут отличаться

Comment: на первом шаге `fragment = 6**2 / 1`; на втором `6**2/1 * 6/2 = 6**3/2!`; на третьем `6**3/2! * 6/3 = 6**4/3!` и так далее

Comment: А можете сказать number за что отвечает за степень или за корень ?

Comment: только за корень и факториал

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!